# problem with shared boundaries of contours in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to get the maximum area object in an image.
I applied a Blur Kernel 5x5 then I applied the Canny algo to get the edges. Then I used the `findContours` method and the max `contourArea` but it returns the wrong object.

Base Image:
[image]

Canny Image:
[image]

Image with all contours found:
[image]

Max area object:
[image]

As you can see it has to return the left box but it returns the right one.
I think the problem is that left and right boxes share a common edge but it seems that belongs only to the left one.

This is the code snippet:

```
    img_rgb = cv.imread(img_path)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # blur with a kernel size of 5x5
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    canny = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 50)
    #saving canny image
    cv.imwrite("canny.png", canny)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(canny, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for c in contours:
        cv.drawContours(img_rgb, [c], 0, (randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)), 3)
    #saving image with contours
    cv.imwrite("contours.png", img_rgb)
    max_area_contour = max(contours, key=cv.contourArea)
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(max_area_contour)
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    #saving the image with the biggest contour
    cv.imwrite("max_contour.png", img_rgb)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: to detect the left box and not the right one

Answer (score 0):

I made key function for max as a square of bounding rect and then it works fine:

```
img_rgb = cv.imread(img_path)
img_rgb_init = img_rgb.copy()
gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# blur with a kernel size of 5x5
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
canny = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 50)
#saving canny image
# cv.imwrite("canny.png", canny)
_, thresh = cv.threshold(canny, 127, 255, 0)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    cv.drawContours(img_rgb, [c], 0, (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255)), 3)

#saving image with contours
# cv.imwrite("contours.png", img_rgb)
def bounding_rect_size(in_cnt):
    x, y, w, h =cv.boundingRect(in_cnt)
    return w*h

x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(max(contours,key=bounding_rect_size))
cv.rectangle(img_rgb_init, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv.imshow("",img_rgb_init)
cv.waitKey()
```

The reason it was working incorrect that the contour of bigest rectangle was looking like train railways. In one direction from one side of rectangle line and in other direction from other side (the line somewhere is broken). That is why the area of this contour was small.

Comment: Can you please share the output? It would be complete

Comment: unfortunately It did not work good this solution

Comment: For such tasks there is no solution that works for all cases.

Comment: I know, I do not claim it must work everytime, but this solution is working only for this specific image, it is quite useless